# After updating to 1.8.0_25, I cannot use 32 and 64 bit java interchangeablely

Tags: java, batch-file, 32bit-64bit

I was running jre7 fine, and had both 32 and 64 bit runtime environments installed on my pc. However, after downloading a jdk, I noticed I needed to update my java. So, I did, uninstalled both iterations of java and then installed 32 and 64 bit jdk and jre.

*However*, afterwards, some of my batch files didn't run properly. I did some fiddling and came to the conclusion that I can't have 64 and 32 bit java active at once. i.e., code like

```
java -d32 -jar filename.jar
```

doesn't work, as it says that "This java instance does not support a 32-bit JVM".
That said, the path variable includes both paths, the 64 and 32 bit one.

Furthermore, both the 32 and 64 bit work seperately, if I remove one from the path variable the other one works.
How can I have it so I can use either 32 bit or 64 bit java without changing the path variable each time?

Comment: Symbolic link for java64 & java32?

Comment: Could you elaborate on that?